# ¿Porque no se muestra un dato en vue js con firebase?

Tags: firebase, vue.js

Esto tengo:
El codepen: [mostrar con vue fire](https://codepen.io/jv_13/pen/QqzvMx)

js:

```
    let config = {
        apiKey: "AIzaSyADg_j2wCsHOog0v8EiytCpm4rUdFnbGFs",
        authDomain: "vuefire-38fad.firebaseapp.com",
        databaseURL: "https://vuefire-38fad.firebaseio.com",
        projectId: "vuefire-38fad",
        storageBucket: "vuefire-38fad.appspot.com",
        messagingSenderId: "61468431295"
    }

    let app = firebase.initializeApp(config)

    let db = app.database()

    let crudVuejs = db.ref('update')



new Vue({
    el: '#main',
    firebase:{
        datosfire: crudVuejs
    },
    data:{
        inputDato:''

    },
    methods:{

    }


})
```

Y esto el html:

```
<div id="main" class="container">

    <div class="row">
        <h1>
            {{ datosfire }}
        </h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Solo esto esta en la bd:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PJLYGN

Comment: Veo que estas utilizando VueFire, prueba con this.$firebaseRef.datosfire, para referenciarla

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con lo siguiente:

```
let config = {
apiKey: "AIzaSyADg_j2wCsHOog0v8EiytCpm4rUdFnbGFs",
authDomain: "vuefire-38fad.firebaseapp.com",
databaseURL: "https://vuefire-38fad.firebaseio.com",
projectId: "vuefire-38fad",
storageBucket: "vuefire-38fad.appspot.com",
messagingSenderId: "61468431295"
    }

new Vue({
    el: '#main',
mounted(){
 let app = firebase.initializeApp(config)

let db = app.database()

let _this = this
  db.ref('update').on('value', function(snapshot) {
      _this.datosfire = snapshot.val()
   });
},
    data:{
      datosfire: ""
    },
})
```

Instanciamos la petición con la function reservada de vue js `mounted()`, después hay que usar una variable `_this` para no perder el scope de la instancia vue y poder referirnos al `data` y en la petición a firebase ejecutamos la function `on` para escuchar cualquier cambio en la BD de firebase y la palabra snapshot nos indica el cambio y obtenemos su valor en este caso para pasarlo a la data.

Comment: Podrías explicar que es lo que hace tu código para que la comunidad sepa que se realizó. Gracias.

Comment: listo amigo espero se explique mejor